# Use dictionary as key for another dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there any way for it to be possible to use dictionaries as the keys to another dictionary?
For example:

```
a = {
        {a: 2, b: 4}: 5,
        {a: 5, b: 6}: 8,
    }
```

I tried this and I read up on the error for unhashable type, but this is just mostly out of curiousity incase there is a way?

Comment: only hashable types can be used as keys, and duct are not washable. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Potential XY problem? What are you hoping to do? Perhaps there is a better way.